# while paging in asp.net how to save text box values in grid

Tags: asp.net

hi what is my problem is in grid view  after page loading  i am entering some values in   text box but after pressing the next page  that page values are disappearing..
how can i save and retrieve the values into the grid view ..
i am able to save it in session but how can  i past it into the currect page..

here is my code  i am able to save it into the values but 
after changing other page  again entering into the same page how can i past the values into the corresponding page..

```
Protected Sub Gridview1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
    'Gridview1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    'SetInitialRow()

    Dim pageindex As Integer = Gridview1.PageIndex

    Response.Write(Gridview1.PageIndex.ToString())
    Dim d As Integer = Gridview1.PageCount
    Dim texts As String() = New String(Gridview1.PageSize - 1) {}
    Dim textBox As TextBox
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    For Each row As GridViewRow In Gridview1.Rows
        textBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
        If textBox IsNot Nothing Then
            texts(count) = textBox.Text
        Else
            texts(count) = ""
        End If
        count += 1
    Next

    Session("one" + "pageindex") = texts
    Gridview1.PageIndex= e.NewPageIndex
    SetInitialRow()

    'Dim sessionint As Integer = Session("page" + "pageindex")
    'If Session("page" + "pageindex") IsNot Nothing Then
    '    Dim textBox1 As TextBox
    '    Dim texts1 As String() = DirectCast(Session("page" + "pageindex"), String())
    '    For i As Integer = 0 To Gridview1.Rows.Count - 1
    '        textBox1 = DirectCast(Gridview1.Rows(i).FindControl("textbox"), TextBox)
    '        textBox1.Text = texts(i)
    '    Next
    'End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

what is your datasource to bind to the gridview ?

These are the 2 ways that I have been doing...

- Grab the whole data table and put it into **ViewState("dataTable")**. Do your filtering of rows and data from there.

Everytime you press 'Next Page', update the rows into the  **ViewState("dataTable")**.

Then rebind the gridview with the  ViewState("dataTable").

- Update the database directly when you press "Next Page".